# JavaScript regex to match `abcwxyz01` and `mabcwxyz01` (string + two digit number)

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me to create a regex to match `abcwxyz<two_digit_num>` and `mabcwxyz<two_digit_num>`?

The letters will always be the same but the **two digit number** (always two digits) can be anything form `01` to `99` and the string may sometimes have the letter m at the start.

Comment: @ColBeseder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean to cause offense, annoy anyone or cause a flame war. I posted this question to help me learn -- I have the O'Reilly pocket reference to Regex but I need to see examples to look them up. Please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = /m?abcwxyz<\d{2}>/
```

Without angle brackets:

```
var regex = /m?abcwxyz\d{2}/
```

If you want to ensure that this is the entire string, make sure to anchor your regex (`^` - matches start of string/subject, `$` matches end of string/subject):

```
var regex = /^m?abcwxyz\d{2}$/
```

Comment: I don't think angle brackets are needed. See title.

Comment: Alright, added another regex for completeness :)

Comment: I think he wants to check whether this is the whole string. You should probably add `^` and `$`.

Comment: perhaps, but that is not clearly stated... It's all pretty vague..

Comment: Of course, you can also use `\d\d` instead of `\d{2}`, which is one character shorter and at least arguably a little easier to read.

Comment: Sure, until the requirement changes from "2 digits" to "1 to 3 digits". Personally I find it easier to read `\d{2}` than `\d\d`, since it specifies the pattern, followed by the number of occurances, instead of repeating the pattern. (Although pattern might be a bit harsh for a simple control character)